# how to check conditions inside .then in javascript

Tags: javascript

Existing code(Working fine) :

```
.then((result) => { 
                this.triggerAction(result.id); 
            }).catch((error) => { 
              this.errorMsg(error);
            });
```

when i try to add condition inside the .then throws error.

```
.then((result && result.id) => {
               this.triggerAction(result.id); 
            }).catch((error) => { 
              this.errorMsg(error);
            });
```

I need to check both result and result.id is coming in the response and throws error id if not available in the result .

Comment: `(result)` isn't a condition, its the parameter list to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To throw an error if `result.id` is missing, you should do the following:

```
          .then((result) => {
            if(!result.id) {
               throw new Error("result.id is missing!");
            }
            this.triggerAction(result.id); 
          }).catch((error) => { 
            this.errorMsg(error);
          });
```

You can also do `throw result` if you just want to pass `result` to the `.catch()` block

Answer (score 1):

```
.then((result) => {
          result?.id && this.triggerAction(result.id); 
      
      })
.catch((error) => { 
         this.errorMsg(error);
  });
```

result inside **.then** is the response you receive on success. You can't apply condition on the fly inside function parameters. You have to check inside the callback function. If **results** will have **id** (result?.id) then **this.triggerAction(result.id)** will invoke

I hope it will work.

Thanks :)

Comment: It won't trigger an error on no id..